# how do i get all the menus of wordpress website using wordpress rest api v2?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I want to rendered all the menus of wordpress website using wp rest api v2.attach my all pages response but i didnt understand how to get menu list from this.[image: response of all pages]

Comment: hello, can anyone help me on this please..i m stuck on this..i dont want to add any plugin for this..want to work wp rest v2 api itself.

Comment: I answered another similar question with a (no plugin) solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209381/get-wp-navigation-menu-from-rest-api-v2/274513#274513

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the WP API Menus [1] and then you can fetch the menus using `wp-json/wp-api-menus/v2/menus/`

[1] https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-api-menus/